# Column identification when search on multiple index columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, supabase

I'm using supabase(PostgreSQL). I'm using full text search(on multiple columns using indexing) of PostgreSQL and its working fine but i want to get column identification(which means i want to get a column which is populating results.

For example:

**column name**: name, email, skill, location, indexed_column(in which multiple columns are indexed)

In upper mentioned table i want to search on indexed_column and want to get result with another field(in which field i want a specific column which is populating results)

Comment: If all the columns are merged together in `indexed_column`, there is no way to tell from which column a value originally came from.

Comment: Ok, So how we can achieve this? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Please show us a concrete example of the index and the query that gets the rows you want (but without the label column you want).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single text-search column, for example as a generated column defined with

```
tscol GENERATED ALWAYS AS
   (to_tsvector('english', col1) ||
    to_tsvector('english', col2))
   STORED
```

there is no way you can determine from which column the text originated.

What you can do is search for your search string in the individual columns as well:

```
SELECT id,
       to_tsvector('english', col1) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'string') AS matches_col1,
       to_tsvector('english', col2) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'string') AS matches_col2,
FROM tab
WHERE tscol @@ to_tsquery('english', 'string');
```

That can still be sped up with a single text search index.